# Selecting raster over points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, expression, atlas

In a QGIS-Atlas, I want to display the name of the raster layer that lies under the current atlas feature using an expression. As coverage layer I use a point layer.
I had thought of an expression with `within ()`, but can't call the raster layer.

Something like: `within (layer_property ('$currentfeature of raster','name'), @atlas_pagename)`

Does anyone have a solution?
[image: The current atlas feature is in this case 'Profil 100']
The current atlas feature is in this case *'Profil 100'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for your question. I think this is the only way, that you can do this.

you can set up a custom python function with the advanced function editor. I programmed a function. It is not optimized, but it works:

**In the custom function editor:**

```
from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_raster_layer_name(point,delim,feature, parent):
    point = QgsPointXY(point.asPoint())  # Convert point to QgsPointXY
    # Get the list of raster layers
    raster_layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer)]
    point_in_raster = []
    # Iterate through raster layers and find the one that contains the point
    for layer in raster_layers:
        if layer.extent().contains(point):
            point_in_raster.append(layer.name())
    
    return delim.join(map(str, point_in_raster))

    return None
```

The function works as follows. it looks what rasters are in the current qgis project. If the point is in the extent, then it puts it in the point_in_raster list. In the end, it returns a string with the delimiter ', ' (or else if stated). It is important, that you use the ' xx ' and not the " xx " in the function, else it is not working.

**You can then add the corresponding text field in your atlas layout:**
Again: look that the delimiter is in single ' and not double ".

```
[%get_raster_layer_name($geometry,', ')%]
```

**One option to set up:**

1. Go to the field calculator and open the Function editor
2. Add a new function with the [+] in the bottom left
3. Give the function a name. It does not matter what the name of the .py file is
4. Copy + Paste the code above (from "In the custom function editor:") in the script
5. Click Save/Load Function
6. Go to your Atlas layout and add a new textfield
7. Put [%get_raster_layer_name($geometry,', ')%] in this text field.
   --> If the point only contains one raster-layer, then the delimiter is useless, BUT you have to put it anyways in the text field, because otherwise the function does not work.

The code should look like this:
[image: Final result of list of raster layers]

If you have any problem setting it up, just write me and I can help you.

Cheers,
C

Comment: Hello C,
I'm very sorry that I've only just got around to trying out your solution.
I was able to follow the instructions easily and the approach worked immediately for my atlas. Thank you very much for this perfect solution!
If time permits, I will try to transfer this approach to my geometries and create a column in which the name of each raster image is stored as the source. Geometries and the underlying raster image always come from the same 3D model. I think as an archaeologist you can understand this. 
Nochmal vielen Dank für deine Hilfe!
Janko

Comment: Hi @Janko. That is great. Glad I could help. If you want to create a column, you can easly apply the created python script to create a new field. But you have to be careful if you use the dataformat shape: The maximum field (column) length is 320 characters. Kein Problem :) Grüsse aus der Schweiz